# Add PO lines using Acumatica Contract based SOAP API

Tags: api, acumatica

I am trying to create a PO using Acumatica contract based API. How do I add lines looping through a list of items to add to the PO. All examples I see have code creating a new PurchaseOrderDetails for each item being added to the PO

```
PurchaseOrders purchaseOrders = new PurchaseOrders()
{
    Vendor = new AcumaticaService.StringValue { Value = poList[0].VendorId }
};
purchaseOrders.Details = new PurchaseOrderDetails[]
{
    new PurchaseOrderDetails
    {
        InventoryID = new StringValue  {Value = "3BA0130" } ,
        OrderQty = new DecimalValue {Value = 3}
    },
    new PurchaseOrderDetails
    {
        InventoryID = new StringValue  {Value = "3BA0138" } ,
        OrderQty = new DecimalValue {Value = 5}
    }
};
```

I need to be able to loop through a list of products and add them to the PO. I was expecting to be able to do something like this

```
    foreach (POListProduct pOListProduct in pOListProducts)
    {
       // PurchaseOrderDetails purchaseOrderDetails = new PurchaseOrderDetails()
       {
          PurchaseOrderDetails purchaseOrderDetails = new PurchaseOrderDetails()
          {
            InventoryID = new StringValue { Value = pOListProduct.Product_No },
            OrderQty = new DecimalValue { Value = pOListProduct.AdjustedQuantity }
          };
       };
       purchaseOrders.Details.Add(purchaseOrderDetails);
    }
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on another post about something else. Updating here if anyone else has tis question.

```
            List<PurchaseOrderDetails> pODetail = new List<PurchaseOrderDetails>();

            foreach(POListProduct polp in pOListProduct)
            {
                pODetail.Add(new PurchaseOrderDetails
                {
                    InventoryID = new StringValue { Value = polp.Product_No },
                    OrderQty = new DecimalValue { Value = polp.AdjustedQuantity}
                });
            }

            PurchaseOrders purchaseOrders = new PurchaseOrders()
            {
                Vendor = new AcumaticaService.StringValue { Value = poList[0].VendorId },
                Details = pODetail.ToArray<PurchaseOrderDetails>()
            };
```